# librdkafka not found by CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, librdkafka

I'm trying to use Kafka in a project that uses CMake to be built.

I have librdkafka-dev (version 0.8.6-1.1) installed.

I also tried downloading the project from Git and building it manually, which seem to be successful.

I noticed a README.md file in the librdkafka/packaging/cmake and followed its instructions, successfully creating a CMake build of librdkafka in the directory.

Running the 'cmake' command in my project results in the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findlibrdkafka.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "librdkafka", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "librdkafka" with
  any of the following names:

    librdkafkaConfig.cmake
    librdkafka-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "librdkafka" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "librdkafka_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "librdkafka" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

It is possible that librdkafka is simply the wrong package name to look for rdkafka in a CMakeLists.txt file, but I haven't found out how to add it to CMake without using the Cppkafka wrapper.

So I tried downloading and building Cppkafka (running the `cmake ..` inside its directory's folder), and it results in the following error:

```
-- Build will generate a shared library. Use CPPKAFKA_BUILD_SHARED=0 to perform a static build
-- RdKafkaConfig.cmake not found. Attempting to find module instead...
-- Could NOT find RDKAFKA (missing: RdKafka_LIBRARY_DIR) 
-- Found valid rdkafka version
-- RdKafka module found.
-- Disabling tests because submodule Catch2 isn't checked out
-- Configuring done
CMake Error in src/CMakeLists.txt:
  Target "RdKafka::rdkafka" contains relative path in its
  INTERFACE_LINK_DIRECTORIES:

    "RdKafka_LIBRARY_DIR-NOTFOUND"
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Did you try to do what it tells you in the first error message?

Comment: Do either of `librdkafkaConfig.cmake` or `librdkafka-config.cmake` exist on your system?

Comment: @drescherjm those files do not exist in my system. I imagine they would be created by following the instructions in librdkafka/packaging/cmake/README.md, but those instructions fail to work...

Comment: @drescherjm good point, I have updated the description. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Did you install `libzstd-dev`? I think you don't have the development package installed and that is causing your problem with the missing `zstd_errors.h` headers.

Comment: I have installed libzstd-dev with the `sudo apt install libzstd-dev` command. I have the latest version (0.5.1-1) installed.

Is it possible that I have to manually build the libzstd library?

Comment: Does `zstd_errors.h` exist in a standard location? like /usr/include

Comment: I reinstalled the zstd library and the Cmake build of rdkafka worked! More details in https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/issues/2486

I updated the question to keep only still relevant information, hope this is not a bad practice...

Comment: You probably should have left the info and provided your own answer to the question in the Answers section. Remember that at `StackOverflow` a question must be self contained. No external links to content that may go away in the future. The main purpose of a question is to help future readers with the same problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This solved itself. Apparently, this was a bug with the CppKafka library and was already solved by the developers.

Comment: Could you please say which librdkafka version solved this?  And also possibly a link to the source.